# What kills a vampire?

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-dark-ages

I'm looking to find a definite list of distinct conditions that can result in Final Death for a vampire. I have managed to get a list of most obvious ways, but some of them seem to be house rules and not reflected in the rulebook.

Note, that I'm looking for ways to die, not ways to kill, so "rake him with Gangrel Beast Claws" and "push him into fire" is for me the same answer - death by aggravated damage.

Below I'd like to put a community wiki answer, in which I will start with a list that I have completed in the first place. If you remove anything from it, please state a reason for removal for posterity.

Comment: In my understanding, a variant of point 2 in the accepted answer would be "losing last level of health without enough blood to heal it". Am I right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### 1. Taking aggravated damage while in torpor.

> If your character is reduced to 
>   Incapacitated via lethal damage, and she takes a further 
>   level of aggravated damage, she meets Final Death

Vampire The Masquerade 20th Anniversary p. 285

### 2. Losing last level of health to aggravated damage.

> Worst  of  all,  a  vampire  who  loses  his  last health level due to
>   aggravated damage meets Final  Death

Vampire The Masquerade 20th Anniversary p. 285

That would actually include seemingly differing reasons, such as exposure to sunlight, fire or being diablerised.

### 3. Massive physical trauma (tremendous lethal damage)

> An incapacitated or torpid vampire may also be sent 
>   to  Final  Death  through  massive  amounts  of  bashing 
>   or lethal trauma  (***decapitated***, trapped under a 10-ton 
>   rock, fed into a wood chipper, caught at ground zero 
>   of  an  explosion,  crushed  by  deep-sea  pressure,  etc.)

Vampire The Masquerade 20th Anniversary p. 284

Most of them kill a vampire even if it isn't incapactitated or torpid.

### 4. Heart removal

> ••••• The Heart of Darkness
>      A  Kindred  with  mastery  of  Serpentis 
>   may  pull  her  heart from her body.

Vampire The Masquerade 20th Anniversary p. 210

It is implied that a vampire without access to this discipline would have a bad time removing his heart. It would make sense to assume ripping the heart out makes him go torpid, but I remember a Level 3 thaumaturgy ritual (*Shaft of Belated Quiescence,* page 237) that enchanted a wooden stake so that it splinters and grows into the heart as it is staked. The description claimed that un-staking is possible with multi-hour surgery, but attempting to remove it by force cause Final Death.